# SQL - select first_table_id from linking table where all records in second table are in specified type

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with SQL query. My tables:

```
[work_order]
work_order_id

[link_person_wo]
work_order_id
person_id

[person]
person_id
type
```

I need to get all work_order_id from link_person_id where ALL persons (linked to this work_order) are in type = employee

example:

[image: example]

As a result in this example i would expect ***2, 3***

1 should not be included as it contains also Tech as person.

this is my sql:

```
SELECT work_order_id FROM link_person_wo JOIN person ON person.person_id = link_person_wo.person_id WHERE type = 'Employee' GROUP BY work_order_id
```

It returns all work_order_ids that have at least one person with type employee, i want to get those who has all person in type 'Employee'

Comment: Looks like adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT person.type) = 1` should give the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  work_order_id  from 
(SELECT work_order_id , sum(case when b.type = 'employee' then 1 else 0 end) as cs 
,count(*)  as cnt  
FROM link_person_wo a 
JOIN person b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
group by work_order_id ) 
where cs=cnt
```

Comment: This was the faster query, i had only to add _**AS tmp**_ to get this work
`group by work_order_id ) AS tmp`

, without this i have:
_Every derived table must have its own alias._

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use your same query in reverse, find all work orders where that have non employees and eliminate those from your result set.

```
SELECT work_order_id 
FROM link_person_wo a 
JOIN person b ON a.person_id = b.person_id 
WHERE type = 'Employee' 
    AND work_order_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT work_order_id 
    FROM link_person_wo c
    JOIN person d ON c.person_id = d.person_id 
    WHERE type <> 'Employee' 
    GROUP BY work_order_id)
GROUP BY work_order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the work order IDs for which the number of non-employees is zero:

```
select lp.work_order_id
from link_person_wo lp
join person p using (person_id)
group by lp.work_order_id
having sum(p.type <> 'Employee') = 0;
```